# Why is getpwnam() always returning root information in a function?

Tags: c, root, getpwnam

I wrote a simple program that calls `getpwnam()` on a username, passes that username to a function, and then calls `getpwnam()` again. For some reason, I always get the passwd information for root inside the function.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printuser(char *username) {
  printf("USERNAME2: %s\n", username);
  struct passwd *user_info = getpwnam(username);
  printf("USERNAME3: %s\n", username);
  printf("USERNAME4: %s\n", user_info->pw_name);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct passwd *user_info = getpwnam(argv[1]);
  printf("USERNAME1: %s\n", user_info->pw_name);
  printuser(user_info->pw_name);
  printf("USERNAME5: %s\n", user_info->pw_name);
}
```

The program always produces the following output:

```
$ ./test_getpwnam chenxiaolong
USERNAME1: chenxiaolong
USERNAME2: chenxiaolong
USERNAME3: root
USERNAME4: root
USERNAME5: root
```

I can't find anything in the man page related to this. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The return value may point to a static area which is overwritten by a subsequent call to getpwent(), getpwnam(), or getpwuid().

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwnam.html

In particular, there is no guarantee about the ordering of reads/writes, so it is not safe to pass data returned from `getpwnam` back to `getpwnam`.

You really should not use `getpwnam` at all; use `getpwnam_r` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have read the man page more carefully :)