# How to get a user UID by username in Objective C/C in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos

How do I get a user UID by username in Objective C/C in OS X?
Currently I know how to get UID of user who launched app when I call this code:

```
uid_t uid = getuid();
NSLog(@"uid: %d", uid);
```

But I need to get the user's UID by username.

EDIT:
Also tried:

```
struct passwd *ss = getpwnam("myusername");
NSLog(@"uid: %d", ss->pw_uid);
```

and it returns "502" which is correct. It's heppens in case when I run my application under "myusername".

If I run my app under root using the same code it returns "0" which is incorrect. I expect to receive "502" in both cases because I set parameter "myusername" in both cases.

Comment: Use `struct passwd`, `getpwnam()` & co. from POSIX ([docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/pwd.h.html)).

Comment: OS X is a UNIX, as @user3477950 said the usual POSIX APIs apply for this.

Comment: @DarkDust The OP knows this; he's already using `getuid()` :D

Comment: EDITED topic with results

Comment: Hm, I just tried it myself and it does work correctly for me on Mavericks: it returns the UID of my account no matter whether I run the app as root or normal user. Which version of OS X are you using?

Comment: The same version as my system. And your short test app really queries `getpwnam` and _immediately_ outputs the result? Because if you do another query, [the result may be different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664456/why-is-getpwnam-always-returning-root-information-in-a-function/12664749#12664749). If your test app really is as short as possible and produces the wrong result you might want to file a bug.

Comment: But, when used for another user-name than myself, would I get the uid too? must I run it as root for that purpose?

Comment: Could you please also specify what #import/#include should I use on MacOS-X to have getpwnam() ?